# How to count precisely in try/except in python?

Tags: python

I have a counter for recording idle threads. Each time the idle thread gets job from the queue, then the counter would decrease by 1; after job is done, the counter will be increased by 1. Code like below:

```
while true:
   try:
      self.queue.get() # exception may thrown here
      self.counter -= 1
      # other check goes here
      self.process() # exception may thrown here
      self.counter += 1
   except Exception as err:
      self.counter += 1 # if exception thrown from get(), then it's wrong
```

How do I get the counter right? Any approach to get the counter right no matter exception thrown or not?

Comment: Try `finally`. This is the code from the thread? Then this is also missing a [`task_done()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.task_done).

Comment: What's the problem? Assuming a job is done whether it crashes or finishes properly, it shouldn't matter for the counter. In that case, just move all the counter related stuff outside the try-except clause.

Comment: What do you want to happen if get() throws an exception?

Comment: it will continue to go through try block after exceptions. when get() throw an exception, then we can't increase the counter as it didn't get decreased yet.

Comment: this is the function passed to creating thread thd = threading.Thread(target=self.process)

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have two statements that can trigger the same Exception (or you don't care about which exceptions) and you want different actions to occur, then you will need distinct try/except clauses.

I assume you only want to call process() if get() was successful. Otherwise you have to adjust the indentation in this piece of code, and maybe use a 'finally' in the second try/except.

```
while true:
    try:
       self.queue.get() # exception may thrown here
    except Exception as err:
        pass
    else:
        self.counter -= 1
        try:       
            self.process() # exception may thrown here
        except Exception as err:
            pass
        self.counter += 1
```